# Typing a word in between two aligned equations

Tags: equations, align

Is it possible to type something such as "and" in between these two aligned equations where the arrow mentions?. If so, can anyone kindly tell me how to achieve this?

Here is the screenshot

[image]

and here is my code:

```
\begin{align*}
\bigl(Sf\bigr)\bigl(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k}\bigr) &:= \sum_{\sigma\in S_{k}}
f\bigl(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)} \bigr), \\ 
\bigl(Af \bigr) \bigl(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k}\bigr) 
  &:=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k}} \bigl( \text{sgn\,}\sigma\bigr) 
f\bigl( v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots,v_{\sigma(k)} \bigr).
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mathtools` package has `\shortintertext` for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{align*}
\bigl(Sf\bigr)\bigl(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k}\bigr) &:= \sum_{\sigma\in S_{k}}
f\bigl(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)} \bigr), \\
\shortintertext{and}
\bigl(Af \bigr) &:=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k}} \bigl( \text{sgn\,}\sigma\bigr) 
f\bigl( v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots,v_{\sigma(k)} \bigr).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good but the distance between "and" and the two aligned equation is a bit longer. Is it possible  to make it nearer ?

Comment: What do you mean, longer than what?

Comment: Longer than the expected. I want the word "and" a bit nearer to the two aligned equations. Is it clear ?

Comment: You could use something like `\shortintertext{\hspace*{1cm}and}` to bring it nearer to the center, but I'd vote against this because it will look strange if you have surrounding text as in the example

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: the `\ArrowBetweenLines` command, from `mathtools`, which accepts an optional argument. It has to be used within the `alignedat` environment. Note  I replaced `:=` (where the colon is not centred on the math axis) with `coloneqq`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & & \bigl(Sf\bigr)\bigl(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k}\bigr) & \coloneqq \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k}}
  f\bigl(v_{\sigma (1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma (k)} \bigr), \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines[\text{and }]
    & & \bigl(Af \bigr) & \coloneqq \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k}} \bigl( \text{sgn\,}\sigma \bigr)
  f\bigl( v_{\sigma (1)}, \ldots,v_{\sigma (k)} \bigr).
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, I forgot to check. Fixed now. Thanks for pointing it!